# How to get NSTableView heightOfRow for cell that contains WebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, nstableview

I have an NSTableView that has a single column, with rows that contain a WebKit WebView. The problem I am having is how can I get the size of the WebView so I can set the height in the table view's `heightOfRow:` method.

Here is the relevant parts of code:

```
// The only essential/required tableview dataSource method
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.messagesArray count];
}

// This method is optional if you use bindings to provide the data
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MainCell"]) {

        ChatTableViewCell *cellView = (ChatTableViewCell*)[tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MainCell" owner:self];
        NSString *htmlString = [self.messagesArray objectAtIndex:row];
        [[cellView.webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
        [cellView.webView.mainFrame.frameView setAllowsScrolling:NO];

        return cellView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

The problem I have is how to get the size in this method. Everything I have tried so far is giving me an exception. I think it's because the cell is not initialized properly when the following method is called, and that the WebView method `loadHTMLString` is asynchronous.

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row {
    //What can I put here?
}
```

I want to be able to resize the cell to the same size as the content in the WebView.

EDIT: I tried adding the following to the `heightOfRow` method:

```
    WebView *webView = [((ChatTableViewCell*)[tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:row makeIfNecessary:YES]) webView];
    NSRect webViewRect = [webView frame];
    return webViewRect.size.height;
```

And it gives me the following:

`WARNING: NSTableView detected a rowView was requested from inside of the -heightOfRow delegate method. That is not supported!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will give you the height of the webview content..

Load the webview with html string like this..

```
embedHTML = [embedHTML stringByAppendingFormat:@"<body><div id='size_div'>%@</div></body></html>",YourString];
```

And now in webViewDidFinishLoad method keep this statements...

```
NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"size_div\").offsetHeight;"];  
NSLog(@"height: %@", output);
```

Comment: How do I then change the size of the tableview cell?